# How to write into console or terminal in i386 system on Qemu?

Tags: c, qemu, uart, i386, bare-metal

I am trying to write simple hello world program on Qemu i386 emulator system without any operating system (baremetal). Currently I am able to write into video by writing into an address within a **continuous loop**.

```
u16 *const video = (u16*) 0xB8000;

/* Display a character at x, y in fg foreground color and bg background color.*/

void putc(u8 x, u8 y, enum color fg, enum color bg, char c)
    {
        u16 z = (bg << 12) | (fg << 8) | c;
        video[y * COLS + x] = z;
    }

/* Display a string starting at x, y in fg foreground color and bg background
 * color. Characters in the string are not interpreted (e.g \n, \b, \t,etc.).
 */
void puts(u8 x, u8 y, enum color fg, enum color bg, const char *s)
    {
        for (; *s; s++, x++)
        putc(x, y, fg, bg, *s);
    }
```

I want to write similarly into a console or terminal (using uart) without any formatting. I could find this information for Arm based systems but facing difficulty in finding how to do it for i386 systems. Suggestions?

Comment: So you want to write to a serial port instead of to the screen? What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered with your code? Have you checked [the OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) or other links for help about the serial port hardware?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Probably. Since my main aim is to print some debug information inside my application. AsI am very new to low level programming I assumed writing to terminal could be as simple as writing on to screen. Is there any other method to print debug info or writing a uart serial driver is the only way?

Comment: Using the serial port is the usual way to print debug (or other internal) information on low-level systems. There are many tutorials on how to do it, either by accessing the BIOS or using the hardware directly. See e.g. my previous link to the OSDev wiki for some tutorials and references.

Comment: There is another option with QEMU. You can write characters to port 0x402. To enable this feature you can use `-chardev stdio,id=seabios -device isa-debugcon,iobase=0x402,chardev=seabios` when running QEMU. Each character you output to the port should display on the console